# How to remove duplicate entries from input fields in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('td:even').css('background-color', 'limegreen');
   $('td:odd').css('background-color', 'blue');
    
  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".txt").each(function() {
    
   $(this).change(function(){
    
    calculateSum();
    checkduplicate();
    
    
   });
  });

 });
 function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {
   //add only if the value is number
   if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
   }
  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
  
 }

    function checkduplicate(){
 var sum = 0;
  var arr = [];
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=txt]');
  all.forEach(function(el){
    arr.push(el.value);
    sum += +el.value;
console.log(arr);
console.log(sum);
    var c = arr.filter(i =>i==el.value).length;
    if(c>1){
      var dupe = [...all].filter(e => e.value==el.value);
      dupe.forEach(function(d){
        if(d.value.trim() != ''){
          d.style.border = '5px solid red';
          d.style.color = 'red';
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
      });
    }
    });
   }  
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnClear').click(function(){    
   if(confirm("Want to clear?")){

    /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
    $('#sumtable input[type="txt"]').val(" ");
    /*Reset sum to zero*/
        $("span").html("0");
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
     location.reload();
              $('td:even').css('background-color', 'limegreen');
          $('td:odd').css('background-color', 'blue');
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('td:even').css('background-color', 'limegreen');
   $('td:odd').css('background-color', 'blue');
  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".txt").each(function() {

   $(this).change(function(){
    calculateSum();
    checkduplicate();
     location.reload();
              $('td:even').css('background-color', 'limegreen');
          $('td:odd').css('background-color', 'blue');
    /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
    $('#sumtable input[type="txt"]').val(" ");
    /*Reset sum to zero*/
        $("span").html("0");
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    
   });
  });

 });
    
   }     
  });
 });
```

```css
body {
 
    font-family: sans-serif;
   }
   #summation {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#174C68;
   }
   .txt {
    background-color: #FEFFB0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<head>
<!--<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="/home/cybrosys/Sethu/JS/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="sumbox.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="sumbox.css" type="txt/css">
</head>
<body>
<table  border="2" align="center" id="sumtable">
 <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"   name="txt"    id="qty1" class="form-control alldifferent"></td>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"   name="txt"    id="qty2" class="form-control alldifferent"></td>
          <td><input type="txt"class="txt"    name="txt"    id="qty3" class="form-control alldifferent" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"     name="txt"  id="qty4" class="form-control alldifferent" ></td>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"   name="txt"    id="qty5"  class="form-control alldifferent"></td>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"   name="txt"    id="qty6" class="form-control alldifferent" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"   name="txt"    id="qty7" class="form-control alldifferent" ></td>
          <td><input type="txt"class="txt"     name="txt"   id="qty8"  class="form-control alldifferent"></td>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"    name="txt"   id="qty9"  class="form-control alldifferent"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
<div align="center" >
 <tr id="summation"><br>
  <td align="center">Sum :</td>
  <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td></tr>
  </div>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <div align="center">
         <tr><td><button type="button" id="btnClear" value="reset"/>Reset</td></tr>
</div>
 </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm unable to remove duplicate entries from the input fields and auto focus in those input fields. Also when I click on reset button the sum generated is Nan.

I have 9  input fields where the user can enter the values. Upon entering the values the sum is generated . When the user enters duplicate values those entries are highlighted with red color and the background becomes red too.

I'm trying to remove duplicate entries and auto focus in those fields.
After resetting sum to zero and input fields to null. While entering values again the sum generated is NaN. How to resolve these two problems?

Comment: you have to generate the sum of value when you click the reset button is right or not?

Comment: I dont think you can focus multiple fields at once

Comment: when reset button is clicked reset the value of sum and input fields to zero. Then on keychange the sum of value must be generated.

Comment: <button type="reset" id="btnClear" value="reset"/>Reset</td></tr> change the type to "reset" it will reset the value

Comment: @ chiliNut....no need to focus on multiple fields at once. on keychange we input values to input fields,on doing so if duplicate values are found they have to removed and auto focus on that corresponding field

Comment: @tom...yeah it resets the value . but once reset button is clicked and values are inputted to the fields the sum generated is NaN. the value of sum must be generated while entering values to the input fields.

Comment: is this three rows are fixed? or dynamically changed

Comment: sorry didn't get you Tom. The rows are fixed , the values inside the fields are not fixed

Comment: in table you have 3 rows is fixed? or adding extra rows

Comment: 3 rows are fixed not adding them

Comment: all values in all columns should be taken to perform sum. sum is generated at the bottom of the table.

Comment: K wait.. do have any fiddle

Comment: @tom no I dont have any

Comment: Try action listener to calculate the sum for all text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187704/discussion-between-tom-and-sethu).

Comment: Its already calculating sum using change event. But once reset button is clicked the sum generated upon entering values is nan

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the color when you do the summation and add `d.focus();`. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
         $('td:even').css('background-color', 'limegreen');
   $('td:odd').css('background-color', 'blue');
    
  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".txt").each(function() {
    
   $(this).change(function(){
    
    calculateSum();
    checkduplicate();
    
    
   });
  });

 });
var sum = 0;
 function calculateSum() {
  sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".txt").each(function() {
   //add only if the value is number
   if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
 this.style.color ='limegreen';
        $('td:even').css('background-color', 'limegreen');
          $('td:odd').css('background-color', 'blue');
            this.style.border = 'limegreen';
   }
  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
  
 }

    function checkduplicate(){
 var check=0;
  var arr = [];
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=txt]');
  all.forEach(function(el){
    arr.push(el.value);
    sum += +el.value;
   // console.log(arr);
//console.log(sum);
    var c = arr.filter(i =>i==el.value).length;
    if(c>1){
      var dupe = [...all].filter(e => e.value==el.value);
       check=0;
      dupe.forEach(function(d){
        if(d.value.trim() != ''){
        if (check==0){
        check=1;
        }else{
          d.style.border = '5px solid red';
          d.style.color = 'red';
          d.value="";
          d.focus();}
       
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
else{
 d.style.color ='limegreen';
 $('td:even').css('background-color', 'limegreen');
          $('td:odd').css('background-color', 'blue');
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
      });
    }
    });
   }  
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btnClear').click(function(){    
   if(confirm("Want to clear?")){

    /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
    $('#sumtable input[type="txt"]').val(" ");
    /*Reset sum to zero*/
        $("span").html("0");
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.reload(true);
});
              $('td:even').css('background-color', 'limegreen');
          $('td:odd').css('background-color', 'blue');
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('td:even').css('background-color', 'limegreen');
   $('td:odd').css('background-color', 'blue');
  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".txt").each(function() {

   $(this).change(function(){
    calculateSum();
    checkduplicate();
       setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.reload(true);
});
              $('td:even').css('background-color', 'limegreen');
          $('td:odd').css('background-color', 'blue');
    /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
    $('#sumtable input[type="txt"]').val(" ");
    /*Reset sum to zero*/
        $("span").html("0");
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    
   });
  });

 });
    
   }     
  });
 });
```

```css
body {
 
    font-family: sans-serif;
   }
   #summation {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#174C68;
   }
   .txt {
    background-color: #FEFFB0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<head>
<!--<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="/home/cybrosys/Sethu/JS/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="sumbox.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="sumbox.css" type="txt/css">
</head>
<body>
<table  border="2" align="center" id="sumtable">
 <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"   name="txt"    id="qty1" class="form-control alldifferent"></td>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"   name="txt"    id="qty2" class="form-control alldifferent"></td>
          <td><input type="txt"class="txt"    name="txt"    id="qty3" class="form-control alldifferent" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"     name="txt"  id="qty4" class="form-control alldifferent" ></td>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"   name="txt"    id="qty5"  class="form-control alldifferent"></td>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"   name="txt"    id="qty6" class="form-control alldifferent" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"   name="txt"    id="qty7" class="form-control alldifferent" ></td>
          <td><input type="txt"class="txt"     name="txt"   id="qty8"  class="form-control alldifferent"></td>
          <td><input type="txt" class="txt"    name="txt"   id="qty9"  class="form-control alldifferent"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
<div align="center" >
 <tr id="summation"><br>
  <td align="center">Sum :</td>
  <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td></tr>
  </div>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <div align="center">
         <tr><td><button type="button" id="btnClear" value="reset"/>Reset</td></tr>
</div>
 </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

For FireFox use `location.reload(true);`

Comment: hi @i_th, the sum after resetting input fields is NaN. and im not able to remove duplicate entries and auto focus on them

Comment: @Sethu how can it be. I tried and it works or I didn't get your point. try to use different browser.

Comment: im using mozilla firefox. I ran the edited snippet and tried still same problem

Comment: @Sethu try to use chrome and if it is not working, please specify your problem.

Comment: but irrespective of browser it should be working right?

Comment: how to remove duplicate entries from the input fields?

Comment: I tried giving d.value='' , but it clears the previous value when duplicate entries of the same are found.

Comment: @i_th...how to remove duplicate entries from input fields

Comment: @Sethu check it now.

Comment: @Sethu try it now, It removes only the duplicated because you don't  put `check ==0`

Comment: sry i_th for the reply...got it right in chrome browser, but not working in mozilla

Comment: @Sethu For FireFox use `location.reload(true);`  instead of `location.reload();` it works.

Comment: @Sethu I don't know what do you mean.